# How read multiple .txt files with some missing headers and unwanted columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read about 2000 .txt files which do not all have the same columns. I want to select only the common headers across all files and save these to a csv file to be uploaded into a MySQL database.
I need help parsing these files to select only the columns I need. I only need the following columns: code, startDate,startTime, endDate, endTime, s, number.
There are time columns after startDate and endDate which do not have headers in the files. I have just named them 'startTime' and 'endTime'

As an illustration

file1 sample:

```
code                         startDate        endDate          s   number
-------------------------------------- ------------------- ------------------- - ----------
4000                                   23-04-2010 00:00:00 23-04-2010 00:14:59 E          1
4001                                   23-04-2010 00:00:00 23-04-2010 00:14:59 E          0
4002                                   23-04-2010 00:00:00 23-04-2010 00:14:59 E          0
4003                                   23-04-2010 00:00:00 23-04-2010 00:14:59 E         0
```

file2 sample:

```
code                         lineNum                         startDate        endDate          s   number id description
-------------------------------------- -------------------------------------- ------------------- ------------------- - ---------- ------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3000                                   2111201                                31-10-2010 05:45:00 31-10-2010 05:59:59 E          9                311 CAPITAL
3000                                   2111201                                31-10-2010 05:45:00 31-10-2010 05:59:59 E          4               1411 USUARIO FRECUENTE
3000                                   2111201                                31-10-2010 05:45:00 31-10-2010 05:59:59 E          1               7071 FUNCIONARIO
3000
```

```py
file_list = [file1, file2,...]

datalist = []
for file in file_list[]:
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        reader = f.readlines()
        for line in reader:
            #use regex to search for only rows with text and numbers
            if re.search(r'[0-9a-zA-Z]', line):
                datalist.append(line.strip().split())
    header = datalist[0]
    try:
        repeatingHeaderIndx = datalist[1:].index(header) + 1
        #remove repeating header from data using index  
        datalist.pop(repeatingHeaderIndx)
    except:
        pass      
df = pd.DataFrame(datalist[1:])
```

When I check my complete dataframe, it is getting more than the columns I require because the number of columns in each file may be different.

Comment: Hard to tell from your file samples, but is it possible these are fixed width text files?

Comment: Yes sir, that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your regex to only match the lines that contain either of your columns names-

```
obj = re.compile(r'\b(code|startDate|startTime|endDate|endTime|s|number)\b')
with open('words.txt', 'r') as reader:
   for line in reader:
       match = obj.findall(line)
       datalist.append(match)
```

So your code should look like-

```
file_list = [file1, file2,...]
obj = re.compile(r'\b(code|startDate|startTime|endDate|endTime|s|number)\b')

datalist = []
for file in file_list[]:
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        reader = f.readlines()
        for line in reader:
            match = obj.findall(line)
            if match:
                datalist.append(match)
header = datalist[0]
try:
    repeatingHeaderIndx = datalist[1:].index(header) + 1
    #remove repeating header from data using index  
    datalist.pop(repeatingHeaderIndx)
except:
    pass      
df = pd.DataFrame(datalist[1:])
```

Comment: Yabhishek, thanks for your solution. However 'startTime' and 'endTime' do not exist as headers in the files. On each line there are two time columns (right after startDate and endDate) with no headers that I need as well. So I just added them up as part of the final solution I need.